# How to receive messages from a streaming server?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, streaming, grpc

I am trying to build an asynchronous gRPC C++ client that sends/receives streaming messages to/from server using the `ClientAsyncReaderWriter` instance. The client and the server send messages to each other whenever they want. How can I check if there is any message from the server?

The `ClientAsyncReaderWriter` instance has a binded completion queue. I tried to check the completion queue by calling `Next()` and `AsyncNext()` functions to see if there is any event that would indicate that there is some message from the server. However, the completion queue has no events even if there is a message from the server.

```
class AsyncClient {
public:
    AsyncClient(std::shared_ptr<grpc::Channel> channel) :
        stub_(MyService::NewStub(channel)),
        stream(stub_->AsyncStreamingRPC(&context, &cq, (void *)1))
    {}
    ~AsyncClient()
    {}

    void receiveFromServer() {
        StreamingResponse response;

        // 1. Check if there is any message
        // 2. Read the message
    }

private:
    grpc::ClientContext context;
    grpc::CompletionQueue cq;
    std::shared_ptr<MyService::Stub> stub_;
    std::shared_ptr<grpc::ClientAsyncReaderWriter<StreamingRequest, StreamingResponse>> stream;
};
```

I need to implement steps 1 and 2 in the `receiveFromServer()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortunately, I found a solution to my problem and the asynchronous bi-directional streaming in my project works as expected now.
It turned out that my understanding of the "completion queue" concept was incorrect.
This [example](https://github.com/perumaalgoog/grpc/blob/perugrpc/examples/cpp/helloworld/greeter_async_bidi_client.cc) was a great help for me!